# How to download javax.realtime.RelativeTime?

Tags: java

I have the class `javax.realtime.RelativeTime`. I do not know where to import this class and which jar file I should look. Help me in this regard?

Comment: Have you googled it first ? https://www.google.co.in/search?q=javax.realtime.RelativeTime&oq=javax.realtime.RelativeTime&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.551j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yes but i was unable to found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need RTSJ package. Read this article for details: http://www.denizoguz.com/2009/10/28/preparing-for-real-time-java-development/

BTW are you sure you *really* need this?

Comment: So, do not foreget to upvote and mark the answer as correct :).